# Visual studio 2022 Ui Glitch (help!)

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2022, visual-glitch

I am currently experiencing some technical issues with my Visual Studio 2022 software. Specifically, the user interface seems to be glitching, with no recent projects appearing and a black screen. Although I am able to click "continue without project," I am still met with a white screen at the end.

I have attempted to resolve this issue by trying a repair and a clean reinstallation of the software, but unfortunately, nothing has changed. Additionally, I have also tried other versions of the software, such as Enterprise and Pro, but I am still experiencing the same problem.

I have included some screenshots of the issue for reference. Can anyone provide any suggestions or advice on how to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Screenshots:

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4GTM.jpg)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwvHK.jpg)

Comment: My pc specs:
Winver: WIN10 PRO 22H2(OS BUILD 19045.2604)
I5 10400
16gb ram 2666mhz
3060ti
H510MK GIGABYTE
NVME 500GB

Comment: The second screenshot looks normal when no project is open. The problem however looks like some problem with the graphics driver. Make sure you have the latest graphics card driver installed.